# db2 connecting to a db via alias and storing user name and password

Tags: windows, authentication, users, db2

I created a TCP node and I catalogued a db into it. The catalogued db needs user name and password to be accessed. Is there anyway I can store username and password in the cataologue (or other way)? I use the catalogue in an Excel spreadsheet (OLEDB connection) and every time I need to insert username and password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DB2 won't store your username and password - neither the server, nor the client. What you could do is set up an ODBC setting in Windows. (I am assuming you are using Windows given you mention Excel, though I could be incorrect in that). The ODBC setting allows you to store the username and password on that Windows system. Do be careful with that though as Windows will warn you that the password isn't stored the most securely.

Comment: Thats' correct. I found that I can call Control Panel->Admi Tools->Setup ODBC and on "System DSN" I can setup easily a db connection using all alias of my db2 instance. Thanks a lot.